# Distinct based on window function (sort curiosity or wrong problem approach)

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, group-by, window-functions, distinct

A lot of values are stored in `values`. The data is in a hierarchical order, so there could be a probe, on which some measurements have been performed. Many points have been archived with strain and stress for example. So in the `values` table all the strain/stress values belongs to different objects.

The relation to the probe is stored in another table. In this example the hierarchical order is neglected.

I would like to calculate something on the probe-level, based on the measurements. So i want to group all the stress/strain values in a json, so it is clear they belong together.

Now there should be a second measurement with strain and stress. And i want to calculate values based on all values, but grouped by strain. So there should be a value calculated by the stress, where strain = `2` (for example) of both measurements (the additional level in the hierarchy coming from multiple measurements is neglected too). Yes, and that's not enough: i want to be able to group by multiple values.

In multiple rounds i calculate values based on values of previous rounds.

I made a little [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yx5_kYBw):

- `complex` is a table containing the model info for grouping the data.
  `complex_in` contains the inputs for the aggregated datatype (->json)
  `complex_groupcond` contains the information, by which subvalues (in the json) the calculation should be grouped by `values` (contains the values in json format).
- the second next block is just for inserting initial values and grouping models).
- the third block simulate the first round, building the first complex data_type).
- In the fourth block i have the basics of my query, where the values get joined with the inputs for the complex data type and get grouped by them. Important is the window function for getting the condition of the group by out of the json and the distinct on the same Partition.

So I have some questions (now there is more data so the performance should be improved):

```
Sort Key: "values".name, "values".value_id, complex_in.complex_id
Presorted Key: "values".name, "values".value_id
```

1. The system uses the index `complex_in_pkey` for the join of the `values` and the `complex_in`. Why the system does not recognize, that everything should already be sorted with `complex_in.complex_id` in the next place (because `complex_id` is in the index of `complex_in_pkey`)?
2. Is one approach better, where i join the (prejoined) `values` and `complex_in` with a pre grouped table of `complex_cond`, so the rows of the `prejoin` cant get multiplied with this join. But now its more difficult to extract the grouping condition out of the the complex value (json).
3. Or would be one approach better to leave all the values single and track the hierarchical order where the values comes from. So in the calculation one could order by this hierarchical knowledge. (Not finished thinking about the grouping condition in that case.)

If your are a German speaker, perhaps this [this description](https://www.pg-forum.de/t/join-mit-index-und-group-by/12967) will be clearer.

To make the question more clear:

1. Why the system does not recognize the data is already sorted by "values".name, "values".value_id, complex_in.complex_id? (or isn't that true and why?)
2. Is a join (with `complex_groupcond`) better on a unique key, with the a usage of a new special function (for extracting the data)?
3. Do you have a better idea to approach a problem like that?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking; do you need help formulating a query that returns what you need? Are you not happy about its performance? Something else?

Comment: Oh, im sorry, no im not happy with the performance. I think it takes too much  time to sort the stuff. I just wonder why it has to perform the sorting, altough its using the index.

Comment: In that case take a look at [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the rest of the questions, but in general a merge join can output rows of its second input multiple times, if there are ties in its first input.  It needs to rewind and reread in order to do that.  Those duplicated rows will no longer be in order by extraneous columns of the 2nd input, so the merge join cannot pass through the stipulation that its output preserves the input order on keys other than the ones used by the merge condition itself.

Now in this case, maybe that out-of-order return can't happen due to the primary key constraint on the first input, but inferring that is an optimization which PostgreSQL simply doesn't seem to implement.  This is not unusual, there are many hypothetically possible but unimplemented optimizations.

Comment: Thank you, for the other questions im working on an example with more context.